# How to efficiently INSERT the exact same row save for one changing column?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have to do multiple `INSERT`s of the exact same row except for the `recipient` field, whose value is different for every row. Short of doing a `for/each` loop in PHP to `INSERT` the same row but change the `recipient` field in every iteration, is there a way to more efficiently go about this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. But whether you'll get the efficiency is something you've got to benchmark.

Method 1: First insert all the rows in one batch, then run an update query on a second loop.

I don't like this approach since the efficiency is lost in trying to run a second set of update queries.

But since you're going to be using PHP to run the queries, I'd advice method 2.

Method 2:

1. Build a string to include multiple insert values.

   Insert into MyTable (Field1, Field2, ... Field-N)
   Values (Value1, Value2, Value3, ... Value-N),
   (Value1, Value2, Value3, ... Value-N),
   (Value1, Value2, Value3, ... Value-N)

   You may build the string to a substantial size here. I've built it for 10,000 records in the past.
2. Execute the query by calling the **mysql_query** function.
3. Go back to step 1 until you have no more records to insert.

This method is pretty good if you have huge amounts of inserts. But it's important to keep in mind that a fail in the **Insert** must be trapped to ensure that the correct records are being inserted. Ideally, a transaction commit would help solve this along with the **mysql_affected_rows** function.

And finally, if your numbers aren't so great, build a smaller string. And if your total records is just around fifty or so, just insert them individually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write a `stored procedure` in MySQL to do multiple inserts on the same table using single query call. e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_data
(
 arg_col VARCHAR(255)
,arg_recipient_val_1 VARCHAR(255)
,arg_recipient_val_2 VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_table(col, recipient)
    VALUES(arg_col, arg_recipient_val_1),
          (arg_col, arg_recipient_val_2);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a good read of the [link here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html). You can insert [multiple rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) at the same time, this will make it very easy to re-use variables:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

There are a number of tricks to do.

- Firstly, lock your tables to speed up the insert process.
- Secondly, you can use the multiple insert syntax to insert rows quickly.

An example of the SQL code as below.

```
LOCK TABLES a WRITE;
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (8,26),(6,29);
...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

In terms of SQL efficiency, don't even look at the [replace into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) syntax.

*Please note that REPLACE INTO is a much slower performer than an UPDATE statement. Keep in mind that a REPLACE INTO requires a test on the keys, and if a matching unique key is found on any or all columns, a DELETE FROM is executed, then an INSERT is executed. There's a lot of management of rows involved in this, and if you're doing it frequently, you'll hurt your performance unless you simply cannot do with any other syntax.*